# Angular update component on state change

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on my first angular application and experiencing some issues with updating / re-rendering my component.

In my component, I have an update function that fetches a resource from my backend and saves the result in a variable called taskList.
I would like for the component to be updated / re-rendered every time this function is called.

```
update = async () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/tasks/' + this.date.valueOf();
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const result = await data.json();
    this.taskList = result.tasks
};
```

I display the values of the list like such:

```
<div 
    <div 
        *ngFor="let tasks of taskList" 
        class={{tasks.color}}  
        {{tasks.text}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I then have another case where I add items to the list followed by calling the update function. It successfully updates the taskList variable but doesn't re-render the component.

I have attempted different implementations of *ChangeDetectorRef* that I found online with no success.

Comment: Check this link to make your HTTP calls in an angular way. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient . About your issue: It will be great if you share minimal reproduction example.

Comment: I added more explanation as to how the data is used and what the problem is. @AshotAleqsanyan

Comment: this html template would have syntax errors if that's what it really is in the code

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call the api in the Angular way, I mean you could drop the async/await and just make an ordinary call.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `async` pipe, which can be used to update both for observables and what you're doing here, using Promises. `*ngFor="let tasks of taskList | async"`

That being said, your life will be probably easier if you avoid Promises and go with the http client and observables in Angular.